# React Native element mapping issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm currently building a calendar app where, in this case, you press on a desired date on the calendar and it shows you below all the events related to that day. However, these events have a "dropdown" function to show more data, and when I press on them to toggle the more detailed version of that element, all the events for that day switch to the detailed view.

```
...

const events = [
  { title: 'Maths Exam', date: '2023-04-17', time_start: "HH:MM", time_end: "HH:MM", duration: "HH:MM", teacher: "Ms. Sonila", details: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet" },
  { title: 'English Quiz', date: '2023-04-17', time_start: "HH:MM", time_end: "HH:MM", duration: "HH:MM", teacher: "Ms. Morena", details: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet" },
  { title: 'Albanian Essay', date: '2023-04-17', time_start: "HH:MM", time_end: "HH:MM", duration: "HH:MM", teacher: "Ms. Junilda", details: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet" },
  { title: 'Albanian Project', date: '2023-04-17', time_start: "HH:MM", time_end: "HH:MM", duration: "HH:MM", teacher: "Ms. Junilda", details: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet" },
  { title: 'Albanian Something', date: '2023-04-17', time_start: "HH:MM", time_end: "HH:MM", duration: "HH:MM", teacher: "Ms. Junilda", details: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet" },
];

...

const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10));
  let currentDate = (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]
  let dateSelected = (selectedDate.replaceAll("-", " ")).split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
  const getEventsForDay = (date) => {
    return events.filter((event) => event.date === date);
  };
  const onDayPress = (day) => {
    setSelectedDate(day.dateString);
  };

...

const [isDetailed, setIsDetailed] = useState(false);
  const [isBlock, setIsBlock] = useState("none");
  function toggleView() {
    setIsDetailed(!isDetailed);
    if (isDetailed) {
      setIsBlock("flex")
    } else {
      setIsBlock("none")
    }
  }

...

<Text style={styles.eventsTitle}>Events for {dateSelected}:</Text>
        <ScrollView style={{ height: (calendarHeight / 1.5) + 15 }} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          {getEventsForDay(selectedDate).map((event, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleView} key={index}>
              <Card style={styles.eventItem}>
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.eventItemTitle}>{event.title}</Text>
                  {/* @ts-ignore */}{/* This is to ignore the "display: `${isBlock}`" below as it threw an error. */}
                  <Text style={{ display: `${isBlock}`, color: "white", marginTop: 5 }}>{event.details}</Text>
                </View>
                {isDetailed ? (
                  <Ionicons
                    name="chevron-up"
                    color={Colors.primary}
                    size={25}
                    key={index}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <Ionicons
                    name="chevron-down"
                    color={Colors.primary}
                    size={25}
                    key={index}
                  />
                )
                }
              </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
```

[image: Before detailed view]

[image: After detailed view]

Comment: Can you say more about what the problem is and the expected behavior? As it is it's not that clear what you're asking.

Comment: What i want to happen is when I click on one of the events only that specific card/event gets the detailed view, and not all of them as you can see in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same state to control on/off toggle for the card details. So, all the details will open at once when button is clicked.

If you would like to control it one by one, you need to have more than one state. I would suggest you to create an component for this case.

```
const EventComponent = ({event, index}) =>{

  //Move this component out of parent component to prevent re-render issue

  const [isDetailed, setIsDetailed] = useState(false);
  const [isBlock, setIsBlock] = useState("none");

  function toggleView() {
    setIsDetailed(!isDetailed);
    if (isDetailed) {
      setIsBlock("flex")
    } else {
      setIsBlock("none")
    }
  }

  return(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleView} key={index}>
      <Card style={styles.eventItem}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.eventItemTitle}>{event.title}</Text>
          {/* @ts-ignore */}{/* This is to ignore the "display: `${isBlock}`" below as it threw an error. */}
          <Text style={{ display: `${isBlock}`, color: "white", marginTop: 5 }}>{event.details}</Text>
        </View>
        {isDetailed ? (
          <Ionicons
            name="chevron-up"
            color={Colors.primary}
            size={25}
            key={index}
          />
        ) : (
          <Ionicons
            name="chevron-down"
            color={Colors.primary}
            size={25}
            key={index}
          />
        )
        }
      </Card>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default ParentComponent({navigation}){

  const events = [
    { title: 'Maths Exam', date: '2023-04-17', time_start: "HH:MM", time_end: "HH:MM", duration: "HH:MM", teacher: "Ms. Sonila", details: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet" },
    { title: 'English Quiz', date: '2023-04-17', time_start: "HH:MM", time_end: "HH:MM", duration: "HH:MM", teacher: "Ms. Morena", details: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet" },
    { title: 'Albanian Essay', date: '2023-04-17', time_start: "HH:MM", time_end: "HH:MM", duration: "HH:MM", teacher: "Ms. Junilda", details: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet" },
    { title: 'Albanian Project', date: '2023-04-17', time_start: "HH:MM", time_end: "HH:MM", duration: "HH:MM", teacher: "Ms. Junilda", details: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet" },
    { title: 'Albanian Something', date: '2023-04-17', time_start: "HH:MM", time_end: "HH:MM", duration: "HH:MM", teacher: "Ms. Junilda", details: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet" },
  ];

  ...

  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10));
  let currentDate = (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]
  let dateSelected = (selectedDate.replaceAll("-", " ")).split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
  const getEventsForDay = (date) => {
    return events.filter((event) => event.date === date);
  };
  const onDayPress = (day) => {
    setSelectedDate(day.dateString);
  };

  ...

  return(
    <>
      <Text style={styles.eventsTitle}>Events for {dateSelected}:</Text>
      <ScrollView style={{ height: (calendarHeight / 1.5) + 15 }} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        {getEventsForDay(selectedDate).map((event, index) => (
          <EventComponent 
            event={event}
            index={index}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  )
}
```